# How to Group multiple records to one in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run a query to get Data from two views in my SQL Database. 
First.
I get required columns from my vw_BillsOfLading then I use left outer join to get Pieces and Weight from my item view where my item's transaction Id = bill of lading id.

here is where I have a challenge.

In most cases, I have multiple item records on each bill of lading. Well, I want to show one record for my bill of lading and get the sum of weight and pieces for each bill of lading record.

Please help me and thank you.

Here is my query

```
SELECT
                b.BillOfLadingNumber
              , b.ShipFromCity
              , b.ShipFromState
              , b.ShipFromZip
              , b.DeliveryDate
              , b.ShipToCity
              , b.ShipToState
              , b.ShipToZip
              , i.Weight
              , i.Pieces
              , b.Id
              , i.TransactionId
FROM
                vw_BillsOfLading b
                Left Outer join
                                vw_Items i
                                on
                                                i.TransactionId = b.Id
WHERE
                BillOfLadingNumber in ('100277' ,'100310' ,'100814' ,'100867' ,'101118' ,'101124' ,'101530' ,'101630' ,'101657' ,'101694' ,'101760' ,'102153' ,'102241' ,'102276' ,'102284')
GROUP BY
                b.BillOfLadingNumber
              , b.ShipFromCity
              , b.ShipFromState
              , b.ShipFromZip
              , b.DeliveryDate
              , b.ShipToCity
              , b.ShipToState
              , b.ShipToZip
              , i.Weight
              , i.Pieces
              , b.Id
              , i.TransactionId
```

[image]

Comment: just a subquery? `SELECT BillOfLadingNumber, SUM(Weight)  as Weight, SUM(Pieces ) as Pieces  FROM (your entire query) as a GROUP BY BillOfLadingNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (shooting from the hip here - I don't have a SQL Server instance on this machine):

```
SELECT b.BillOfLadingNumber, b.ShipFromCity, b.ShipFromState, b.ShipFromZip, b.DeliveryDate, b.ShipToCity, b.ShipToState, b.ShipToZip, 
    Sum(i.Weight) as Total_Weight, 
    Sum(i.Pieces) as Piece_Count
FROM vw_BillsOfLading b 
    Left Outer join vw_Items i 
        on i.TransactionId = b.Id
WHERE BillOfLadingNumber in ('100277','100310','100814','100867','101118','101124','101530','101630','101657','101694','101760','102153','102241','102276','102284') 
GROUP BY b.BillOfLadingNumber,b.ShipFromCity, b.ShipFromState, b.ShipFromZip, b.DeliveryDate, b.ShipToCity, b.ShipToState, b.ShipToZip
```

Comment: This is perfect it did it, I can't select your answer yet since it's been four minutes, thank you very, very much!

Comment: @Frank you should accept the answer, if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `i.weight` and `i.pieces` from your grouping:

```
select b.billofladingnumber, b.shipfromcity, b.shipfromstate, b.shipfromzip, b.deliverydate, b.shiptocity, b.shiptostate, b.shiptozip, , b.id, i.transactionid, sum(i.weight) weight, sum(i.pieces) pieces
from vw_billsoflading b left outer join vw_items i on i.transactionid = b.id
where billofladingnumber in ('100277','100310','100814','100867','101118','101124','101530','101630','101657','101694','101760','102153','102241','102276','102284') 
group by b.billofladingnumber, b.shipfromcity, b.shipfromstate, b.shipfromzip, b.deliverydate, b.shiptocity, b.shiptostate, b.shiptozip, , b.id, i.transactionid
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum is your friend:

```
SELECT
    b.BillOfLadingNumber
  , b.ShipFromCity
  , b.ShipFromState
  , b.ShipFromZip
  , b.DeliveryDate
  , b.ShipToCity
  , b.ShipToState
  , b.ShipToZip
  , i.Weight
  , i.Pieces
  , b.Id
  , i.TransactionId
FROM
    vw_BillsOfLading b
    Left Outer join
        vw_Items i
        on
            i.TransactionId = b.Id
WHERE
    BillOfLadingNumber in ('100277' ,'100310' ,'100814' ,'100867' ,'101118' ,'101124' ,'101530' ,'101630' ,'101657' ,'101694' ,'101760' ,'102153' ,'102241' ,'102276' ,'102284')
GROUP BY
    b.BillOfLadingNumber
  , b.ShipFromCity
  , b.ShipFromState
  , b.ShipFromZip
  , b.DeliveryDate
  , b.ShipToCity
  , b.ShipToState
  , b.ShipToZip
  , i.Weight
  , i.Pieces
  , b.Id
  , i.TransactionId
```